# Form does not validate. csrf_token included

Tags: python-3.x, flask, jinja2, flask-wtforms, wtforms

I have following issue with validate_on_submit() method in my Flask application.

Quick overview what I have:

My form class is created dynamically based on input:

```
class EditUsers(FlaskForm):

    submit = SubmitField('Submit')

def form_builder(roles_list):

    class EditUsersForm(EditUsers):
        pass

    for role in roles_list:
        if isinstance(role, tuple) and len(role) == 5:
            if not role[2] and role[3]:
                setattr(EditUsersForm, f'{role[0]}_{role[4]}_bool', BooleanField(label=role[0]))
                setattr(EditUsersForm, f'{role[0]}_{role[4]}_date', SelectField('Expiration Period', choices=choices))
        else:
            raise IncorrectType
```

IncorrectType is custom Exception i prepared and choices are created using datetime in same file (This is irrelevant so I am not including it in code).

My route in flask app (simplified):

```
#### EDIT: I pasted the wrong route, POST and GET Methods are included###
@edit_users.route('/users', methods=['GET', 'POST'])

def users():
...  # Some code there
form = form_builder(roles_to_form)

print(form.is_submitted())
print(form.validate())
print(form.validate_on_submit())

return render_template('edit_user.html',
                       data_dict=data_dict,  # in data_dict i pass form fields names and some other data
                       form=form,
                       )
```

My template:

```
<!-- Some usual stuff goes there css js etc -->

<div >
    <form class="form form-horizontal" method="post" role="form" style="margin: auto; text-align: center; width: 40%;">
        {{ form.csrf_token() }}
        <table class="table" align="center">
            <thead>
                <th>Role</th>
                <th>Expiration Date</th>
                <th>Give Role?</th>
            </thead>
            {% for field in data_dict['id_list'] %}
            <tr>
                <td align="left">{{ field[2] }}</td>
                <td align="left">
                    {{ form[field[1]] }}
                </td>
                <td align="left">{{ form[field[0]] }}</td>
            </tr>
            {% endfor %}
            <tr>
                <td colspan="3" align="center">{{ form.submit() }}</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</div>
```

**What is my issue?**

When I am hitting my Submit button, `is_submitted()` returns True but `validate()` does not, thus I cannot use typical `if form.validated_on_submit()` as it returns False even when I submit my form.

I dig a little and spot something unusual. I used protected members of form attributes, to check whatever validate() function sees as input:

```
for name in form._fields:
    print(name)
    inline = getattr(form.__class__, 'validate_%s' % name, None)
    print(inline)
```

The output (don't mind names of fields):

*submit*

*None*

*Engineer_2_bool*

*None*

*Engineer_2_date*

*None*

*Operator_3_bool*

*None*

*Operator_3_date*

*None*

*Supervisor_4_bool*

*None*

*Supervisor_4_date*

*None*

*Guest_5_bool*

*None*

*Guest_5_date*

*None*

*csrf_token*

*None*

I don't know why my form does not have `validate_{name}` attributes.

Comment: There's not enough information here to go off of.  Is `choices` a list of strings or a list of tuples?  Have you checked the output of `form.errors` after your call to `form.validate()`?  (Just do a `print(form.errors)` after `print(form.validate())`)

Comment: @tresni I checked errors recently and indeed the problem was with ```choices```. I forgot to change its type from datetime.datetime to str. Thanks for input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with type of data passed to choices of `SelectField`. I passed list of tuples with `datetime.datetime` to it. When changed type to `str` everything works smoothly.

Answer (score 1):

I made a working example from your code, and I ended up with the problem you described.

If I reversed well your code, it seems that `form[field[1]]` is your BooleanField or SelectField. So to render it in a template your have to use  `form[field[1]]()` (can use render_field as well).
So :

```
<tr>
    <td align="left">{{ field[2] }}</td>
    <td align="left">
        {{ form[field[1]] }}
    </td>
    <td align="left">{{ form[field[0]] }}</td>
</tr>
```

corrected into :

```
<tr>
    <td align="left">{{ field[2] }}</td>
    <td align="left">
        {{ form[field[1]]() }}
    </td>
    <td align="left">{{ form[field[0]]() }}</td>
</tr>
```

https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/patterns/wtforms/#forms-in-templates

<s>As you are using a FlaskForm, in your template you have to replace `{{ form.csrf_token() }}` by `{{ form.csrf_token }}`
https://flask-wtf.readthedocs.io/en/stable/csrf.html#html-forms
[EDIT Does not make any difference]</s>

[Edited after w8eight's comment]
The route is not authorized for POST (and the form makes a POST request as seen in  `<form class="form form-horizontal" method="post" [...]`.
So you have to change : `@edit_users.route('/users', methods=['GET'])` to `@edit_users.route('/users', methods=['GET','POST'])`

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't change the form behavior. It is still not validated after I press submit button

Comment: Just made a correction to my answer. I missed that POST methods were not allowed

Comment: Good catch, but unfortunately this is my mistake when creating question, not in code. In my code both methods are passed to route, I edited my question accordingly

Comment: Thanks a lot for help, the problem was with my choices, i forgot to change type from datetime to str